# CSS Calc: Why percentage doesnt work correctly in calc function?

Tags: css, percentage, calc

I want to create a calendar and  position 7 days on the same line:

```css
.calendar{
  height: 40%;
  width: 40%;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: lightgray;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.days{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding-inline: .2rem;
}
.days div{
  font-size: .875rem;
  width: calc((40% - .4rem) / 7);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="calendar">
  <div class="month">
    <div class="date">
      <h1>JUNE</h1>
      <p>Wed Jun 08 2023</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="weekdays">
     <div>Mon</div>
     <div>Tue</div>
     <div>Wed</div>
     <div>Thu</div>
     <div>Fri</div>
     <div>Sat</div>
     <div>Sun</div>
  </div>
  <div class="days">
    <div class="empty"></div>
    <div class="empty"></div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div class="today">8</div>
    <div>9</div>
    <div>10</div>
    <div>11</div>
    <div>12</div>
    <div>13</div>
    <div>14</div>
    <div>15</div>
    <div>16</div>
    <div>17</div>
    <div>18</div>
    <div>19</div>
    <div>20</div>
    <div>21</div>
    <div>22</div>
    <div>23</div>
    <div>24</div>
    <div>25</div>
    <div>26</div>
    <div>27</div>
    <div>28</div>
    <div>29</div>
    <div>30</div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

1st question: why doesn't the `calc()` function work here in `.days`, especially when I use percentage?

2nd question: when I change percentage in rem it works and fits perfectly, what is the reason?

Can someone explain it to me, please. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

your calc function is work good. when you set a width by percentage (like 40%) its mean width of your div is **40% of width of its parent** that in code equal to 40% of 40%(parent is .calendar). but you need width of your day qual to `1/7` of total calendar width that is equal to `100% / 7`

```css
.calendar{
  height: 40%;
  width: 40%;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: lightgray;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.days, .weekdays{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding-inline: .2rem;
}
.days div, .weekdays div{
  font-size: .875rem;
  width: calc((100% - .4rem) / 7);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="calendar">
  <div class="month">
    <div class="date">
      <h1>JUNE</h1>
      <p>Wed Jun 08 2023</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="weekdays">
     <div>Mon</div>
     <div>Tue</div>
     <div>Wed</div>
     <div>Thu</div>
     <div>Fri</div>
     <div>Sat</div>
     <div>Sun</div>
  </div>
  <div class="days">
    <div class="empty"></div>
    <div class="empty"></div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div class="today">8</div>
    <div>9</div>
    <div>10</div>
    <div>11</div>
    <div>12</div>
    <div>13</div>
    <div>14</div>
    <div>15</div>
    <div>16</div>
    <div>17</div>
    <div>18</div>
    <div>19</div>
    <div>20</div>
    <div>21</div>
    <div>22</div>
    <div>23</div>
    <div>24</div>
    <div>25</div>
    <div>26</div>
    <div>27</div>
    <div>28</div>
    <div>29</div>
    <div>30</div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but of course how could I make this mistake, thank you @Amir Mazinani